# Proper SE site to ask about scientific approach to telepathy juggling

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have seen some video of juggling on BBC by some **mind reading** and **projecting the feeling of one body to another** and some other tricks like inserting some thing inside a sealed Coke bottle (that I guess could be related to **controlling the brain** of the camera man and others in the juggling room).

So, I googled about telepathy and saw some video like [this](http://You%20read%20my%20mind:%20scientists%20claim%20%27first%20telepathy%20success%27%20%7C%20Channel%204%20News), that science is doing this by **reading EEG signals** and sending to other sensor as **visual signal** or **audio signal**; so if that telepathy and syncing the persons to other is real maybe they have some system behind this ability. Maybe something like this experience discussed in [this ted talk video (claimed about the some capability in one schizophrenia patients)](https://www.ted.com/talks/eleanor_longden_the_voices_in_my_head/transcript?language=ru) or said in [this tedtalk video about how the ancient believed about creativeness in genius (some unknown connection system !!)](https://www.ted.com/talks/elizabeth_gilbert_your_elusive_creative_genius) and somethings like [this, which is said it would be so hard by quantum entitlement to do it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fl8GvPRvikM) !

So I tried to read about the [**jugglery telepathy psychology**](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=20&q=jugglery%20telepathy%20psychology&hl=en&as_sdt=1,5&as_ylo=2016) term in Google Scholar to find some paper to read the scientific hypothesis behind that, but did not find anything (maybe because I don't know the proper tags, or not spending more time on search).

So I would like to ask on one SE site about the science hypothesis that **could make possible telepathy and syncing the persons together by sense and do the same works at one time**

**Update:**

Maybe it's more related to **[psychology](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fpsychology.stackexchange.com%2F%20telepathy&oq=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fpsychology.stackexchange.com%2F%20telepathyy&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.4659j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)** or **physics** SE Site!

Comment: As a word of advice, I would encourage you to take a hint of a lack of references in quality sources as a hint of the lack of any scientific basis behind this (and many other) supernatural phenomena.

Comment: No, it's definitely not appropriate on psychology or physics. If you want to know why, take @Murenik's advice and ask a well-posed question about it on [Skeptics.se].

Comment: 'woo.com', presumably:)

Answer (score 11):

[Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) sounds like a reasonable place to ask, although you may not like the answers you'll get there.

Comment: Worth mentioning is that Skeptics requires a "notable claim". Find someone that says these things are 'real' and not an illusion, and challenge that claim.

Comment: Freud ans some others opened this topic and ... described [here](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/17983/can-we-interconnect-with-other-people-mentally-during-dreaming), Do them enough to be considered as unknown phenomena that we have not scientific rules that have it could happened?